# Analytics Filter to attribute a specific landing page to a certain referrer?

Tags: html, google-analytics

our business advertises on the classifieds website www.kijiji.ca, and as part of that they have a link back to our website on all of our advertisements. In what looks to be an effort to prevent tab-nabbing, kijiji recently added rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" to their 'referral' links. This had the unfortunate side-effect of breaking analytics for me, and any other person who advertises on kijiji.

I've taken this up with Kijiji, but as I suspect it's a security concern on their part I doubt they'll be open to changing it. They are currently investigating the issue.

At the same time as the original change, they forced '/referral=kijiji' to the end of any URL passed into their website link field. So, my question is if anyone knows of a way to configure a filter in analytics which sees that url and causes the hit to be attributed as a referral.

Of course, as a work around you can just go into the Landing Pages report and search for '/refferal=kijiji', but that breaks reporting and causes your Mediums/Sources reporting to falsely attribute referrals as direct traffic.

If anyone has a workaround I'd be very grateful! Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, there isn't a way to set a referrer after the data has been collected by GA as raw GA data is not modifiable.  You could send a [virtual pageview](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages#tracking_virtual_pageviews) with a utm parameter for attribution purposes.  Keep in mind that this will inflate your pageviews count and will also consider the session to be a non-bounce.

If it were me, I'd fire an event when I detected '/referral=kijiji' in the URL and then create a segment of sessions that included the event.  Be sure to use a [non-interaction event](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events#non-interaction_events) so that your bounce rate isn't affected.